# How to find instantaneous velocity at t = 2s with initial velocity given (What am I doing wrong?)

Tags: integration, physics, kinematics

For this question, the acceleration function is given as: a(t) = 4t - 2t^2 + 25e-t/F, with F being a constant equal to 1. The initial velocity given is 35 m/s.

I'm trying to find the velocity at t = 2s, where I've already integrated the acceleration function to get the function for velocity, which is: v(t) = 2t^2 + (2/3)t^3 - 25e^(-t) + 60. The 60 is the constant of integration that I found through substituting 0 for t into the velocity equation and setting it equal to the initial velocity (35 m/s).

I was able to find the correct value for the velocity at t = 1s  (53.47 m/s), but for some reason, I just can't seem to figure out why I can't get the right answer for t = 2s. At first I thought it was because of the new initial velocity being the value that was discovered at t = 1s, but solving for the constant just brings me back to the original constant, which was 60.

There might be something conceptually that I'm also missing, which is probably the most likely reason as to why I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong.

The wrong answers that I've come up with so far are: 70.67, 64.13, 73.33, and 69.95 (one of them is a calculator error I think)

Comment: Is the correct answer given to you somewhere? Also shouldn't that be $-(2/3) t^3$?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that, it's 59.28
There's another question right after that asks for t = 3s, but if I understand how the t = 2s solution works then I'll probably be fine on my own for that one

Comment: Is your acceleration supposed to be $a(t) = 4t - 2t^2 + 25e^{-t} - F$?